# Можно ли сказать "кошка виляет хвостом"?

Tags: лексика

Разрешите пожалуйста спор, можно ли сказать "кошка **виляет** хвостом"? Или же глагол "вилять" по отношению к этому животному не используется? С уважением,
Наталья

Answer (score 5):

> Или же глагол "вилять" по отношению к этому животному не используется?

Почему бы такая несправедливость? Нет, вполне может. И кошки, и собаки - и все их дикие сородичи только тем и занимаются, что хвостом ***виляют***. Или "вертят" - по сути это синоним. Причем делают это по-разному в зависимости от настроения и ситуации.

Тут у вас, видимо, сказалось переносное значение "вилять хвостом" = "хитрить". Оно связано прежде всего с лисой (считается, что она так следы путает), поэтому поведение кошки может не подходить под этот стереотип. Но в прямом значении - вполне. Лисье виляние - только один из типов возможного, а кошкам дана другая способность - выражать вилянием хвоста ту или иную эмоцию.

Comment: @behemothus, Я не хочу влезать в Ваши разговоры (хотя в целом согласен больше с Вами), но нельзя не признать, что вариант понимания "заискивать, подхалимничать" в принципе возможен. Его дает некий словарь синонимов (по вашему же поиску). Что оно такое этот словарь, я не знаю, но то, что они говорят, языку не противоречит.   .

Comment: @Morkovkin Да видел я тот словарь. Я серьезно к нему не отношусь не потому, что он "левый", а потому, что он не дает второго значения, основного, которое приведено во всех остальных. Т. е. он не дополняет, а отрицает то, что говорят все остальные, даже не упоминая. Это для меня приговор. По сути. я не отрицаю, что кем-то когда-то  "виляние хвостом" может восприниматься как признак подхалимажа. Но по контексту, да еще связанному с собакой (у собачьих это скорее признак дружбы, расположения, заискивают они "в положении лежа" и тихо поскуливая, хвост поджат) - не проходит.

Comment: Но самое главное: я же выбрал то значение, которое объясняло бы  недоумение автора в отношении кошки. А предлагаемое альтернативное - ну никак для этой цели не годится. И вдруг - на тебе, я оказывается и тут неправ. Типа, если сказал, что кашу надо есть ложкой, то я неправ, ибо ложкой едят щи. А щей-то сегодня на столе нету.

Comment: OK, понял.-----

Comment: По отношению к кошачьим "виляет хвостом" вызывает у меня сильное внутреннее сопротивление. Можете ли вы сказать так про льва или тигра? Лучше заменить на "дёргает хвостом", "водит хвостом" , даже "машет хвостом".

Answer (score 2):

ВИЛЯТЬ, 1. чем. Двигать из стороны в сторону (хвостом, бёдрами и т.п.). В. хвостом.

**Кошка может вилять хвостом, то есть двигать им из стороны в сторону, но это только одно из движений ее хвоста.**

[Что представляет собой хвост кошки? | kotkoshka.ru](http://kotkoshka.ru/kak-opredelit-povedenie-koshek-po-hvostu/)

У кошки невероятно гибкий хвост, который она может ловко **изгибать и вилять им в разные стороны**. Это происходит благодаря тому, что между позвонков у кошки находятся суставные щели, в которых располагается своеобразная гелевая субстанция. Эта субстанция позволяет смазывать позвонки между собой и плавно **двигать хвостом во всех направлениях**.

Из Интернета

Тут существует **целый спектр движений**: кошка двигает хвостом из стороны в сторону или сверху вниз, она то плавно покачивает им, то молотит, словно хлыстом .Кошка **виляет хвостом** и перед тем как напасть на жертву — она пригибается к земле, готовясь к прыжку...Если кошка "виляет" хвостом, когда вы с ней производите какое-то действие, значит она недовольна, и просит вас от неё отстать пока ещё культурно.